# How many weight convolution layer has?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a simple convolution network:

```
import torch.nn as nn 

class model(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, ks=1):
    super(model, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=4, out_channels=32, kernel_size=ks, stride=1)

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8*8*32*ks, 64)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)

def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = self.fc2(x)
    return x

cnn = model(1)
```

Since the kernel size is `1` and the output channel is `32`, I assume that there should be `32*1*1` weights in this layer. But, when I ask `pytorch` about the shape of the weight matrix `cnn.conv1.weight.shape`, it returns `torch.Size([32, 4, 1, 1])`. Why the number of input channel should matter on the weight of a `conv2d` layer?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It matters because you are doing 2D convolution over the images which means the depth of the filter(kernel) must be equal to the number of in_channels(pytorch sets it for you) so the true kernel size is `[in_channels,1,1]`. On the other hands we can say that out_channels number is the number of kernels so the number of `weights = number of kernels * size of kernel = out_channels * (in_channels * kernel_size)`. Here is 2D conv with 3D input
[image]

Comment: Why does the filter need `depth` when I did not set anything?

Comment: you set it when you chose Conv2d. You are telling pytorch to set the kernel `depth` to `in_channel` in order for the computations to complete. if you choose Conv3d then the the result of `conv1.weight.shape` will be `torch.Size([32, 1, 1, 1])` and if you choose Conv1d the result of  `conv1.weight.shape` will be either `torch.Size([32, 4, wedth, 1])` or `torch.Size([32, 1, 1, height])`  Check the image i added to the answer